# scanning matrix one row at a time

Tags: c, matrix, scanf

I want to scan a 2-D matrix for **integers** row wise i.e. one row at a time in 'C'

For example:
if matrix is:

```
1 2 3  
4 5 6  
7 8 9
```

then there should be only 3 time scanf be used and first time input be

```
1 2 3
```

at once and so on for other row.

for character we can use something like:

```
char mat[10][10];
scanf("%s[^\n]%*c", mat[i]);
```

similar is possible for integers?

Comment: why don't you give three elements of array to `scanf("%d%d%d",&mat[i],&mat[i+1],&mat[i+2])` of course you need to take for the `out-of-bound` access.

Comment: Only three times `scanf` ? may be you can take them as string and then extract numbers from them

Comment: @Uchia Itachi I think you forgot '&' before mat[i]

Comment: @uchaia: actually i am automating some task and these i/p will come from there. I just wanted to make sure if there is way to scan space separated integers?

Comment: @P0W: ya this will be my last option. first i am trying to get a way to read in integer format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the number of columns or lines, then you can do something like this:

Read each line one by one into a string. Then split the current line on the space character (using e.g. [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok)), and use e.g. [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) to parse the string into an integer.

Like this pseudo-code

```
while (fgets(line))
{
    number_string = strtok(line, " ");
    while (number_string != NULL)
    {
        mat[i++][j++] = strtol(number_string, NULL, 10);
        number_string = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}
```